My previously healthy avocado plant was pruned bare and has since been turning brown on top

My previously healthy avocado plant was pruned bare by my daughter who was trying to help. And now the stem has been steadily turning brown from the top downward. It is hot here and a couple of the pruned leaves were showing possible sun damage, but no disease. The top of the stem had new growth which has since shriveled up and dried up. Should I clip off the brown part? It is almost all of the stem at this point.
Please help...
Thank you!

Sure, avocados are persistent.  Cut it back to where the stem is still alive and water it more during hot and dry periods.  It will bud out at the top after at least three to four weeks.
Keep in mind that avocados want to be trees and it is rare that cutting it back makes it more bushy.
